# What's the standard RMS and peak level for ringtones?

Tags: mastering

Could you tell me what is the correct standard rms or lufs level and peak level for ringtones? Is there anything else relative with the making of a ringtone as a product that I should take into account?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I found the information here useful when creating ringtones. Perhaps you could contact the creator directly and ask him, or get a set of his tones as research. *i am in no way affiliated with the site. http://cleartones.net/about/

Comment: I saw it. Useful link thanks. I may ask him. Actually his demo doesn't seem to be so loud.

Comment: Oh ok he had the volume level of the player down. Finally he has a decent amount of loudness. I measured them and found that they are pretty loud about -11 LUFS intergrated and the peak level was at -0.7 dbfs.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer from Noikia Design Team:
We usually master for "cd", around -10 RMS (or -14 RMS for softer songs) and peak at -0.2. We leave full bandwidth sound as it is, but apparently some manufacturers cut everything below 200 Hz.

Phone speakers typically can't reproduce much frequencies below 500 Hz. Also, 1 kHz can be a problematic frequency. If it's crowded there, the small speaker membrane may start 'rattling' in higher modes and that's not pretty :-) Always test in a phone or a couple of phones.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any real standards. You could however compare the rms or lufs of several ringtones from current phones (samsung,apple,etc.). Have you tried that?

Comment: +1 and to add on I reckon -0.1dB might be a safe bet. They are meant to be loud anyways. I don't think a phone would have a digital gain so the only control it has is to go softer. Which then means your sound should be the loudest it can be without distorting the mobile phone's speaker.

Comment: I have an old mobile but I could ask a friend to send me one to test it. I red a tutorial from a software named sound studio4 and it recommends a peak level between -6 and -12 dB which I find too low. It doesn't say anything about rms though. I heard some ringtones in nokia soundcloud. Some of them seem to be loud but I don't know if this is the real level for ringtones or an audio demonstration for the internet with different level. https://soundcloud.com/nokia-design-team